# stop jquery sliding effect while navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a notification `div` that shows some important information for the customers. This `div` slide up an beep once if there is a new notifications and doesn't hide until customer click the close button and it will not show again for the same notifications.

My problem is :
if the customer doesn't close this `div` while navigation the `div` keep sliding up on each page and give that annoying beep every time.
**I want the div to stop sliding and beeping while navigation**

Comment: you can update in your database with.. `UPDATE notification SET receiver_read = 'yes'`... this is only an idea..

Comment: thank you .. but this will stop the effect for all customers .. so i think it should be a Jquery solution

Comment: maybe this help you: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: thanks it helps a great plugin to create cookie